# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position x

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, getjson

Well I know this question is asked many times. But this one is different.

I'm using getJSON to get some data from Database. The result that is returned is a valid JSON (checked by several JSON validators), but I receive the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 1618

which has a special character in it which doesn't show up in the above error.

This is the screenshot of the error message:

[image]

the character at position 1618 is a space (code is 32), and it is inside a text value.

Here is the JSON text:

```
{"headers":["default","fa-ir","en-us"],"results":[{"id":14,"default":"آذربایجان شرقی","fa-ir":"آذربایجان شرقی","en-us":""},{"id":15,"default":"آذربایجان غربی","fa-ir":"آذربایجان غربی","en-us":""},{"id":16,"default":"اردبیل","fa-ir":"اردبیل","en-us":""},{"id":17,"default":"اصفهان","fa-ir":"اصفهان","en-us":""},{"id":18,"default":"البرز","fa-ir":"البرز","en-us":""},{"id":19,"default":"ایلام","fa-ir":"ایلام","en-us":""},{"id":20,"default":"بوشهر","fa-ir":"بوشهر","en-us":""},{"id":21,"default":"تهران","fa-ir":"تهران","en-us":""},{"id":22,"default":"چهارمحال و بختیاری","fa-ir":"چهارمحال و بختیاری","en-us":""},{"id":23,"default":"خراسان جنوبی","fa-ir":"خراسان جنوبی","en-us":""},{"id":24,"default":"خراسان رضوی","fa-ir":"خراسان رضوی","en-us":""},{"id":25,"default":"خراسان شمالی","fa-ir":"خراسان شمالی","en-us":""},{"id":26,"default":"خوزستان","fa-ir":"خوزستان","en-us":""},{"id":27,"default":"زنجان","fa-ir":"زنجان","en-us":""},{"id":28,"default":"سمنان","fa-ir":"سمنان","en-us":""},{"id":29,"default":"سیستان و بلوچستان","fa-ir":"سیستان و بلوچستان","en-us":""},{"id":30,"default":"فارس","fa-ir":"فارس","en-us":""},{"id":31,"default":"قزوین","fa-ir":"قزوین","en-us":""},{"id":32,"default":"قم","fa-ir":"قم","en-us":""},{"id":33,"default":"کردستان","fa-ir":"کردستان","en-us":""},{"id":34,"default":"کرمان","fa-ir":"کرمان","en-us":""},{"id":35,"default":"کرمانشاه","fa-ir":"کرمانشاه","en-us":""},{"id":36,"default":"کهگیلویه و بویراحمد","fa-ir":"کهگیلویه و بویراحمد","en-us":""},{"id":37,"default":"گلستان","fa-ir":"گلستان","en-us":""},{"id":38,"default":"گیلان","fa-ir":"گیلان","en-us":""},{"id":39,"default":"لرستان ","fa-ir":"لرستان ","en-us":""},{"id":40,"default":"مازندران","fa-ir":"مرکزی","en-us":""},{"id":41,"default":"هرمزگان","fa-ir":"هرمزگان","en-us":""},{"id":42,"default":"همدان","fa-ir":"همدان","en-us":""},{"id":43,"default":"یزد","fa-ir":"یزد","en-us":""}]}
```

Comment: If possible post the json text.

Comment: Check if you copy pasted an unknown character into the json, try copy pasting the json in a notepad editor and then paste it back and try

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I added the json code

Comment: @ShintuJoseph the json is generated server side from database, and it was working correctly.the code is not alter so, it has to be something in the values (as they are only thing added to database). but json validators validate the json code

Comment: Its working fine for me on the browser, after pasting it on notepad

Comment: What browser are you using, and what's the `Content-Type` on the server's response?

Comment: Jus was fiddling on chrome, dint setup a formal server response

Comment: I should clarify that my question was directed at @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. :-)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Try this: `$.getJSON('https://repro.webscript.io/json', function (data) { console.log(data); });` I made my own endpoint that returns the same JSON, and things seem to work there. If that fails for you, we'll know it's browser-specific (or maybe jQuery-version-specific?). If it succeeds for you, we can start to debug what's different about your server's response versus mine.

Comment: @smarx the json is unicode but yours show some different characters

Comment: @smartx please change the url to: `http://sabad123.com/ajax/update-input.aspx?t=province&id=8` (instead of `https://repro.webscript.io/json`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON (retrieved from http://sabad123.com/ajax/update-input.aspx?t=province&id=8) has a tab (`"\t"`) at character 1618, right here:

```
...{"id":39,"default":"لرستان \t",...
```

This is failing to parse in Python's JSON parser as well as `$.getJSON`.

I would next take a look at how you're producing this JSON. Since it doesn't seem to be valid, there may be a bug in whatever's producing it.

At the very least, you can fix up this specific data problem by getting rid of the tab.

**EDIT**

Note that, indeed, per the JSON spec, a tab is not an allowed character in a JSON string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19799355/94559. I think `\u0009` is the proper way to escape the tab character.

Comment: you are a Genius. Thanks a lot.