# This JSON from the book Beginning CouchDB is invalid. I can't find the error?

Tags: json

JSON from the book Beginning CouchDB.

```
    {
"language": "javascript",
    "views": {
        "get_fax_or_email": {
            "map": "function(doc) {if(doc.name && doc.email && doc.fax)
                emit(doc._id, {Name: doc.name, Email: doc.email, Fax: doc.fax});
                else if(doc.name && doc.email)
                emit(doc._id, {Name: doc.name, Email: doc.email});
                else if(doc.name && doc.fax)
                emit(doc._id, {Name: doc.name, Fax: doc.fax});
            }"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you point out the error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 3 opening ``{`` and 4 closing ``}`` ... or not - one ``}`` is inside a string...

Comment: You have a tab in the whitespaces before ``"map":`` - I think this is not allowed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799006/unable-to-parse-tab-in-json-files

Comment: Thank you BitTickler, Indeed, } was the problem.