# JOSN.parse function not working correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I'm trying to parse simple json(string), but I'm getting error.
This is object which I need to get

```
{
"heading" : "The movies",
"box5" : "Click on icon to add text.",
"box1" : "At the movies,you can watch for an hour. ",
"box2" : "You can go eat popcorn,candy,and soda. ",
"box7" : "At the movies you will want to go again. ",
"box3" : "At the movies ,you can play games.",
"box4" : "you can go and have fun with your friends and family.And get to spent time with them.========                ",
"box6" : "Click on icon to add text."
};
```

> .========

I think this is regular string characters

When I remove ========                 I got result

```js
var st = '{"heading": "The movies","box5": "Click on icon to add text.","box1": "At the movies,you can watch for an hour. ","box2": "You can go eat popcorn,candy,and soda. ","box7": "At the movies you will want to go again. ","box3": "At the movies ,you can play games.","box4": "you can go and have fun with your friends and family.And get to spent time with them.","box6": "Click on icon to add text."}';
console.log(st);

var res = JSON.parse(st);

console.log('res: ' + res.heading);
```

included

```js
var st = '{"heading": "The movies","box5": "Click on icon to add text.","box1": "At the movies,you can watch for an hour. ","box2": "You can go eat popcorn,candy,and soda. ","box7": "At the movies you will want to go again. ","box3": "At the movies ,you can play games.","box4": "you can go and have fun with your friends and family.And get to spent time with them.========                ","box6": "Click on icon to add text."}';

console.log(st);

var res = JSON.parse(st);

console.log('res' + res.heading);
```

Comment: I’m not getting any error.

Comment: Please show your JSON (**just** your JSON) in one code block and your code in another. What's there now is a mish-mash, including a `;` in what appears to be your JSON (which would be invalid), so it's hard to help you.

Comment: If we assume your JSON is the part from `{` through `}` and not including the `;`, then the JSON is fine.

Comment: What's the string of white space after the equal signs? Is it a series of carriage returns? This would break the JSON

Comment: Your "example" also works just fine, although it is using a lot of backslashes that are unnecesary. Neither `{` nor `\{` has no special meaning in string literals, so that ends up just being `{`, and you don't need to escape `"` inside a string quoted with `'`. But it works.

Comment: @abosancic: Don't try to put it in a comment, use the "edit" link on the question. But again, it works just fine, so this clearly isn't the actual JSON you're having trouble with.

Comment: Again: That code works just fine, literal copy-and-paste: https://jsfiddle.net/3xyceo1m/

Comment: One of those space characters after the equality signs is actually a tab character. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799006/unable-to-parse-tab-in-json-files

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abosancic/Lxmkqe5a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is problem. String ".========                 " contains tab and this is problem here. After replace tab with space parsing working fine.

Answer (score -2):

try with this string

```html
var obj = '{"heading":"The movies","box5":"Click on icon to add text.","box1":"At the movies,you can watch for an hour. ","box2":"You can go eat popcorn,candy,and soda. ","box7":"At the movies you will want to go again. ","box3":"At the movies ,you can play games.","box4":"you can go and have fun with your friends and family.And get to spent time with them.========                ","box6":"Click on icon to add text."}'

alert(JSON.parse(obj)); //works for me
```

but it works for you but it doesn't for in your page try checking if something is overriding the JSON.parse method or if the string you are using contains single quotes or double quotes at some point