# JSON.parse failes when there is a TAB in the text?

Tags: json

Seems like JSON.parse will not parse text containing tab

```
THIS WILL WORK
THIS WILL NOT WORK <TAB>
```

Is there a way to tell JSON lib to ignore whitespaces?

```js
var userInfo = JSON.parse('{"Address":"ADDRESS WITH NO TABS","city":"Port Blair","name":"User1"}');
  alert(userInfo.Address);
userInfo = JSON.parse('{"Address":"ADDRESS WITH THREE TABS  \t\t\t\t","city":"Port Blair","name":"User1"}');
  alert(userInfo.Address);
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799006/unable-to-parse-tab-in-json-files

Comment: you need to escape them like "ADDRESS WITH THREE TABS  \\t\\t\\t\\t"