# jsonDecode does not handle \t in JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have some JSON data that has \t in it. The flutter jsonDecode function produces an Exception error "Control character in string..." If I replace the \t with a space, no exceptions.

I have used this JSON data with React Native and it doesn't balk at the \t in the data.

Is this a problem with jsonDecode? I know how to massage the data before I feed it to jsonDecode - but it seems like a bug. What am I missing?

Comment: A tab character where?  Within a string?  That's not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19799006/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. When I wrote: tabs (\t) in the title, I truly meant \t. There are no tab characters in the string. I agree that tab **characters** are not allowed in JSON strings.

There are \t 's in the string which by my reading of the JSON spec are allowed. The Dart jsonDecode function rejects strings with \t 's in them as I mentioned.

Please show me how I am either not using jsonDecode properly or misreading the JSON spec.

Thanks for your patience.